# FlexSlider width calculation bug, content being pushed left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have a problem with the widths being calculated on a Flexslider. Intermittently, on load, the LI's inside the FlexSlider seem to be pushed to the left by about 10-15px, thus displaying the first 10-15px of the next slide. See screenshot here: http://goo.gl/N3xOsa. Live preview here: http://goo.gl/3rxYqr. The problem goes away when you click a Nav Control button.

This problem is intermittent, refresh browser if you can't at first see it.

Comment: looks fine for me, what browser are you using?

Comment: Hi Guavacat, thanks for having a look. I'm using Chrome, I just clicked the above live link and had to refresh about 4-5 times to see the problem. It's intermittent. Sometimes I can see the problem on the first load. Does not seem to happen in Firefox, but have encountered it in Safari and Opera. Just tested in Safari and problem showed first time.